# how to sort by groups to get an object with id

Tags: javascript, sorting, ecmascript-6

I have object who users and group

```
 users : [
  {
    id: "5",
    name: "Mandy"
  },
  {
    id: "6",
    name: "Carla"
  },
  {
    id: "7",
    name: "Jacob"
  },
    {
    id: "8",
    name: "Timi"
  }
],
 groups : [
  {
    users: ["5", "6"],
    id: "22",
    name: "group 1"
  },
    {
    users: ["7"],
    id: "33",
    name: "group 2"
  }
] 
}
```

I have this function who return objects group : 5,6 : {     users: ["5", "6"],
id: "22",
name: "group 1" }

```
const Group = obj.groups.reduce((group,currentItem) => {
  if (!group[currentItem.users]) group[currentItem.users] = [];
  group[currentItem.users].push(currentItem)
  
  console.log(typeof group[currentItem.users])
  
  return group
},{})

console.log(usersGroup) -> return object

console.log(Group[7],'Group 7') -> return object 
console.log(Group['5,6'],'userGroup 6') -> return undefinde
```

I would like my function to return id group: -> string after Group[user.id] -> id group
example Group[5] return -> 22

exmaple jsFiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/z9hemu2s/1/

Comment: Didn't understand what you are trying to achieve here but check your in call function which is passed to reduce method `currentItem.users` is an array not a number. Please check you call back function.

Comment: currentItem.users is array, here example -> https://jsfiddle.net/z9hemu2s/1/